# Can't ping VirtualBox Windows 7 VM from separate OS X machine

Tags: windows-7, macos, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a VirtualBox VM running Windows 7 on one Macbook, and have tried unsuccessfully to ping the VM's IP from another Macbook. Here is what I've tried so far:

- I have turned off the 2 Windows firewalls (for Private and Public networks).
- I have enabled Remote Login on the Macbook which the VM is installed on.
  On the VM settings.
- Adapter 1 is a NAT adapter with a port forwarding rule in place. The host IP is localhost (127.0.0.1), the Host Port is 2222, the Guest IP is the IP that I get from the Windows command line inside the VM by running the "ipconfig" command, and the guest port is 22. (NOTE: I think I set this up when I was following instructions on how to ssh into the Windows VM from the other Macbook).
- Adapter 2 is a bridged adapter, with a "Name" setting of "en1: Wi-Fi (Airport)".

I am able to ping both the host machine's IP address and the other Macbook's IP from inside the VM. I just can't do the reverse.  Also, I am able to SSH from one Macbook into the other Macbook, just not from one Macbook into the Windows VM hosted on the other Macbook.  I tried the 'ssh' command via the OS X command line and using the RBrowser GUI app, and neither one worked.

Eventually I'm trying to SSH into the VM from either of the Macbooks, but for now I'd settle for a successful ping.

Advice is appreciated.

EDIT: The following IPs were obtained by using 'ifconfig | grep inet' in UNIX for the 2 Macbooks, and 'ipconfig' inside the Windows 7 VM: 
 - Macbook #1 (w/o VM): 10.0.0.7
 - Macbook #2: 10.0.0.10
 - Windows VM: 10.0.2.15

These IPs look unusually... simple? To be safe, I also checked my IP against the website ip-adress.eu and saw something closer to what I expected- 67.180.49.20. The trouble is I got this same IP for both Macbooks, which isn't what I expected. Also, I tried switching the VM to bridged mode and was unable to ping from the VM to the other Macbook.

EDIT #2- Here are the subnet masks:

- Macbook #1: 0xffffff00
- Macbook #2: also 0xffffff00
- Windows VM: 255.255.255.0.

These values were obtained using the same commands as above. I'm concerned that they don't use the same format. What, if anything, did I miss? FWIW I followed the instructions for finding a UNIX subnet mask from here ([cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-subnet-mask-on-unix](http://cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-subnet-mask-on-unix)) and for finding a Windows subnet mask here ([wikihow.com/Find-Your-Subnet-Mask](http://wikihow.com/Find-Your-Subnet-Mask)).

EDIT #3- I can SSH from the VM into the Macbook that the VM sits on, but not from the VM to the other Macbook.

Comment: What type of network adapter does the Windows 7 VM have configured in the virtual box settings?

Comment: Ok so the network adapter for the Windows 7 VM is configured to be NAT?  That's your problem.  Set the adapter to use bridged mode and everything will work.

Comment: Please post the internal ip addresses/subnet masks for each of the machines involved.

Comment: We are going to need to continue this in chat if you have some time

Comment: The reason we need to continue in chat is there is no way I can explain what the issue is in 500 characters.   Basically your windows vm is on a different subnet than the two other macs, but the reason you can communicate between the machine hosting the vm and the vm is because  the network connection is NATed to that machines network adapter, so only that machine can communicate with it.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34275/toomanyrichs-chat-room